# Xamarin ios 14 permissions not showing in device settings

Tags: xamarin, ios14, ios-permissions

My Xamarin app is not showing all the permissions I have set up on the app settings screen, when running on an ios 14 device. They appeared correctly in earlier ios versions.

I have the following entitlements set up in the info.plist:

- NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription - "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description"
- NSCameraUsageDescription - "Privacy - Camera Usage Description"

Can anyone tell me if ios 14 requires a different set of entitlements? I have not been able to find any developer notes on this, any links pointing me in the right direction would be a huge help!

Thanks

Comment: Did you request the permissions at runtime?

Comment: @Cheesebaron Yes. Though I would expect them to all be listed on the application info settings page on the device as soon as the application is installed. Shouldn't that be the case?

Comment: @Shaboboo Hi, it seems there is no difference used with your shared permissions between iOS 13 and 14.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Thank you for confirming that for me. If there are no changes then I am stumped why they would not be showing up in the app settings...

Comment: @Cheesebaron I didn't understand your comment at first, but you're spot on. The permissions do not show in the list until after you've requested them at runtime. A bit annoying, but I can work with it. If you'd like to write an official answer I will accept it. Thanks